# How to solve this system of non-linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm a bit stumped at how to approach this set of non-linear differential equations. Could someone point me in the right direction in solving them?

System of equations:

$$\dot{p}_{11}(t)=4p_{12}^2(t)+4p_{12}(t)-2$$
$$\dot{p}_{12}(t)=-p_{11}(t)-p_{12}(t)+2p_{22}(t)+4p_{12}(t)p_{22}(t)-3$$
$$\dot{p}_{22}(t)=-2p_{12}(t)-2p_{22}(t)+4p_{22}^2(t)-5$$

Final conditions:

$$p_{11}(5)=1$$
$$p_{12}(5)=0.5$$
$$p_{22}(5)=2$$

---

Another way to express this system of equations is:

$$f'(t)=4g^2(t)+4g(t)-2$$
$$g'(t)=-f(t)-g(t)+2h(t)+4g(t)h(t)-3$$
$$h'(t)=-2g(t)-2h(t)+4h^2(t)-5$$

Where

$$f(5)=1$$
$$g(5)=0.5$$
$$h(5)=2$$

Thank you all in advance for your help. I deeply appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a numerical solution to your system. Here are the values of the functions at $t=0$

$$ [t= 0,f \left( t \right) = 1.736079,g \left( t \right) = 0.3659732,h\left( t \right) = 1.472899]$$

Notice that, for $t>5$, it seems there is a singularity. The three functions, $f(t),g(t),h(t)$ have the following plots respectively

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to add that I found the same numerical solutions: http://i.imgur.com/DpuTS.png

Comment: @in_wolfram_we_trust: Thanks for doing that.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I have one follow up question: how can I solve this myself?

Comment: @Kashif: Just use [numerical methods](http://www.unf.edu/~mzhan/chapter5.pdf) for solving ode's.